# my seed phrase got stolen, what can I do?

Tags: metamask, wallets, meta-transactions

My MetaMask seed phrase got compromised and the hacker drained all of my funds :( Is there anything I can do to try to recover the funds or at least to identify the fraudster? I filed a police report and contacted MetaMask support at Consensys, not sure what else can I do.

My wallet addr: 0x3ce975b9a66a755ed77e75c352f5e827389daba1

Hackers wallets:

https://debank.com/profile/0x42b765308631f81ddb9af5bf2cf16beddbc5c777/history
https://debank.com/profile/0xe688ef90074b28318a14379a3f137af401236a5b/history

Also trying to understand how could it leak.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't much that can be done beyond what you have already did. Metamask credentials are stored on your device so there's nothing they could do. Perhaps you can make a list where you used the mnemonic phrase, it could be a malware in your computer or you used it in a phony site, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Recovering stolen funds can be extremely difficult, as blockchain transactions are often irreversible.  However, by working with law enforcement, contacting support, and analyzing the blockchain data, you may have a chance to identify the fraudster.  Be cautious of any individuals or services claiming they can recover your funds for a fee, as they are often scams themselves.